# Host file configuration in Windows

Tags: windows, web-applications

I want to access a web application located on a server in the same network as my PC .

I have put a new entry in **host** file i.e :

`192.168.10.0 //server ipAddress  foo.boo //hostname used in web browser for accessing the application`

It works fine like this . The application though , is exposed only on a certain port number , so if i want to access it i have to type `foo.boo:portnumber` in my web browser.

Is there any way to make it work without having to type the port number ?

I tried this in Windows host file:

`192.168.10.0:8080     foo.boo`

> This site can't be reached .

Any ideas ?

Comment: The host file doesn't support port numbers. You'd need to configure the service to listen on a different port, reverse proxy it or iptables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible with host files and also not via a local DNS.

You could  try to use a reverse proxy to map this to a standard port.